# How to use javascript or jquery to achieve page search keyword function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a need to search for keywords in the input area, and only the matching keywords will be displayed on the page and the words will be turned red! I searched on the Internet and can use jquery to complete it, but I failed ~ I hope I can get your help, thank you

```js
   
let inputValue = document.querySelector('#keyWord').value;
console.log(inputValue)
$('#js-search').on('click', function() {
  $("p:contains(inputValue)").css('color', 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="keyWord" type="text"><button id="js-search">search</button>

<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Here is some text you can search to display keywords, but the text in the title does not need to be marked</p>
  </li>ㄏ
  <li>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Here is some text you can search to display keywords, but the text in the title does not need to be marked</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Here is some text you can search to display keywords, but the text in the title does not need to be marked</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Here is some text you can search to display keywords, but the text in the title does not need to be marked</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have `$('search')` which is not a proper selector, there is no element with the tage `search`. Did yoolu mean a ID or Class selector, like `#js-search` or `.search`?

Comment: Sorry, I am still a beginner in programming, I think I made a mistake! It should be written like this is correct

let inputValue = document.querySelector('#keyWord').value;
$('#js-search').on('click',function(){
  $("p:contains(inputValue)").css('color','red');
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#js-search').click(function() {
    $("p:contains(" + $('#keyWord').val() + ")").css('color', 'red');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="keyWord" type="text"><button id="js-search">search</button>

<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Here is some text you can search to display keywords, but the text in the title does not need to be marked</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Here is some text you can search to display keywords, but the text in the title does not need to be marked</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Here is some text you can search to display keywords, but the text in the title does not need to be marked</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Here is some text you can search to display keywords, but the text in the title does not need to be marked</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can use `inputValue` variable if you choose, yet I do not see any advantage. Also defining it before the `click` event will cause it to be empty. In your code, it would execute when the page loaded not when the button was clicked. You would end up capturing the value at the wrong time.

For `contains`, you want to concatenate it with the value. See More: [:contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

With `$("p:contains(inputValue)")` the selector will look for the text `inputValue`. Whereas, `$("p:contains(" + inputValue + ")")` will concatenate into whatever was entered as the `inputValue` variable.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply, I think it's great! But there is a problem that this kind of search seems to make all the text turn red. What should I do if I only want the entered keywords to turn red? For example: I entered is and only the is in the p tag will change color, not the entire text.

Comment: @AWEI This would require a more complex snippet of code. Essentially, since the Text Node does not have any markup, you need to A) Find the node that contains that text and B) replace the matching word or phrase with an HTML Element so that you can specifically markup that word instead of the whole text node.

Comment: That's it~ Is it difficult to realize such a requirement? Since I haven't learned programming for a long time, if I have to use a more complicated method, I'm afraid I won't be able to achieve it! So can't the found keywords be highlighted like the search method using ctrl + F?

Comment: @AWEI yes they can be, yet the `:contains()` selector just selects the element that contains that matching text. there are methods to wrap the text so you can highlight it with HTML or you can manipulate the Cursor such that the text is highlighted. from your brief description, it's not clear what you want to do. I would encourage you to mark this answer to this question and research other methods. If you need more help, post a new question.